# Change to app.config while running unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, app-config

I want to run some unittests. For this tests I need to use another value from the app.config file then the default value.

In this post "[Reload app.config with nunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949696/reload-app-config-with-nunit)", I found a solution.

However when running multiple test at once, some test fail, because the old configuration file (app.config) is not called after disposing the function. How could this be ?

Comment: Commenting because this is not an immediate solution to your question:  I always create a 'configuration provider' class to wrap access to the app.config file so that I can mock out the configuration in unit tests without having to worry about changing any files.  You might want to consider this for a design change in you application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found a good solution but for now I use another test project which uses a different app.config

Answer (score 7):

Did you think of wrapping access to the configuration settings in a class? This way you could mock configuration settings in your tests either by using some mocking framework or by creating your own mocks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not really a solution for my question. I dont't want to change my code just for testing purposes.