# App.config for .Net assembly run from PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, sharepoint-2010, app-config

I have a SharePoint 2010 feature that creates a site using a custom site definition that has some code behind on the creation of the site.
I'm trying to deactivate and activate this feature from PowerShell, deactivation is fine but the activation fails on creating the site because I need a database connection string found in web.config

I have tried adding the connection string to an app.config file and loading it with `[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", $config_path)` where $config_path is the absolute path to my app.config but it still fails and if I try to read the connection string from `[Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::ConnectionStrings['name']` (with name substituted to the real name) it gives me an empty string.

I tried the above code after reading about it here on SO and on some other places.

Does anybody know any other way to load the app.config file or a good way to check if it is loaded except the one I was using?

Answer (score 0):

If yours is a class library running inside an asp.net application, settings are taken from the web.config of that website. not sure about SP but try to add your connection string to the SP's web.config.

**Edit:** I did not get you earlier, now I understand this better, you are loading your assembly from powershell so you should use a specific syntax to "inject" your app.config for your class library.

here is your solution, see most voted answer: [Powershell Calling .NET Assembly that uses App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835862/powershell-calling-net-assembly-that-uses-app-config)

Comment: The settings are in the web.config for SharePoint but for some reason the code doesn't read them. I'm about 99% certain that the problem is not getting the connection string because if it gets the connection string and something else goes wrong there's try-catch inside every method that logs to the database. What I have read is that using PS against SP won't read the web.config but everything about this is everything but good documented.

Comment: Your edit links to one of the posts that made me use the rows I used.