# PowerShell DirectorySearcher returns some data and then errors with "More data is available" -- how Can I get the more data?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am using PowerShell to find all users that have direct reports. The query seems to work in that it returns some data, but then it errors with a message.

How can I get the rest of the data?

```
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("GC://DC=prod,DC=org,DC=example,DC=com")

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$objSearcher.ReferralChasing = [DirectoryServices.ReferralChasingOption]::None

$objSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(customAttribute=*123456*)(directReports=*))"

$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange("mail".Split(","))

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
{
    Write-Output $objResult.Properties.Item("mail")
}
```

This is the output with the error at the end:

```
user1@org.example.com
user2@org.example.com
user3@verizonconnect.com
user4@org.example.com
user5@verizonwireless.com
More data is available.
At line:15 char:10
+ foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
+          ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], DirectoryServicesCOMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException
```

Comment: Add a Try/Catch exception handler inside the foreach so code continues after the first exception.

Comment: Are you running this on an older OS?

Comment: Does it work if you take out the line where you're disabling referral chasing?

Comment: @jdweng But the error is on the for loop. If I wrap the entire for loop in a try/catch, then it will just end/stop. Is there a way to continue to the next iteration?

Comment: @GabrielLuci No. Latest version of Windows 10. And no, removing that line does not fix it. In fact, I added the line to try to fix.

Comment: It's odd because I've never seen this, and I have a program I wrote in C# using `DirectorySearcher` with a query that returns every user in our multi-domain forest successfully. Does it stop consistently after a specific number of results?

Comment: I said inside the for loop.

Comment: Right, but does it stop after 5 users? 10 users? 1000 users? Is it always the exact same number?

Comment: You could also try a smaller page size, maybe 500 or even 100.

Comment: @GabrielLuci It consistently stops after the same number of results for that filter. So `filter query 1` returns 5 rows and then errors, every time, and `filter query 2` returns X rows and then errors, every time.

Comment: @jdweng But the error is not being thrown _inside_ the for loop. It is being thrown in the for statement: `foreach ($objResult in $colResults)`. Or am I misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Changing `PageSize`, `ClientTimeout`, `ServerTimeLimit`, and `ServerPageTimeLimit` did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, but I can't test it since I've never seen this error.

A solution (or really, a workaround) documented [around the internet](https://documentation.agilepoint.com/supportportal/docs/productdocumentation/05.00.0200/documentationlibrary/maps/kbSynchronizationNotification.html) is to use an app.config file that looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="system.directoryservices" 
    type="System.DirectoryServices.SearchWaitHandler, 
    System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> 
</configSections>
<system.directoryservices>
    <DirectorySearcher waitForPagedSearchData="true" /> 
</system.directoryservices>
</configuration>
```

.NET applications use an app.config or web.config file by default, but PowerShell doesn't of course. But using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/835984/1202807) it looks like you can tell PowerShell to use a config file, like this:

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", $config_path)
```

Where `$config_path` is the path to your app.config file.

You may or may not need to change the version in the config file to `4.0.0.0`.